# Running a DocumentApp.getUi() alert only once to inform new feature

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api, add-on

I have a docs add-on, where I need to display the user about its new updates and features by calling an alert in onOpen(e) function. With an important point that, only once in a lifetime

OR

Like a don't display again button.

How do I do it?

```
function onOpen(e) {
    DocumentApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
        .addItem('ez-notes', 'Sidebar')
        .addToUi();
    DocumentApp.getUi().alert("new feature..."); //will trouble user everytime.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a reserved function name called `onInstall()`

It is used for Add-ons.  It only runs when the Add-on is installed.

```
function onInstall() {}
```

This will not run whenever a new version of your Add-on is published.  If you want some code to only run once per new published version, then you will need to store both the current version and the last version that the user used somewhere, and then compare them when some code runs.  You can save what the version number SHOULD BE in Properties Service, in the Script Properties or hard code the current version number.  Every time that the oOpen() function runs, you will need to run some server code that compares the current version to the last known saved version that the user used.

I have a function that does nothing but return what the current newest version should be, and I change that number whenever a new version is published:

```
function newestVersion() {return "12";}// Return the newest version number

function onOpen() {
  var newestVersion,lastUsedVersion;

  newestVersion = newestVersion();//Call function to get the newest version
  lastUsedVersion = fncGetLastUsedVersion();//Run function to get last used version

  if (lastUsedVersion !== newestVersion) {
     //Display message

     //Save new value of Last Used Version to User or Document Properties

  }
}

function lastUsedVersion() {
  //Get last used version from User or Document Properties

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this, this may be more complicated than Sandy's version- however I used it in a past script:

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

function onOpen() {
 
  var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
  Utilities.sleep(100) 
  var checkOpen = documentProperties.getProperty('checkOpenStatus');
  Utilities.sleep(100) 

   
    if(checkOpen == "true") {

    }
    else {
    newfeature();
    }
    };

  
    function newfeature() {
    var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('New feature');
    var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
      
    // add the html panel
    app.add(app.createHTML("<b>New features</b><br><br><b>1.</b>New feature text"));
    
      // adds checkbox
    var cBox = app.createCheckBox("Do Not show this on Load").setName("chk1").setId("chk1");
    
    // set check box stuff
    var cBoxClick = app.createServerClickHandler('checked');
    cBoxClick.addCallbackElement(cBox);
    cBox.addClickHandler(cBoxClick);
    app.add(cBox);
    app.add(panel);
    doc.show(app);
    return app;
    
    }

    function checked(e) {
    var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
    
    if (e.parameter.chk1 == "true") 
    { 
    var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    Utilities.sleep(100) 
    documentProperties.setProperty('checkOpenStatus', 'true');
    } 
    else 
    { 
    var documentProperties = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties();
    Utilities.sleep(100) 
    documentProperties.setProperty('checkOpenStatus', 'false');
    } 
    return app;
    }
```